# O365 : TenantUsage_getOffice365ActiveUserDetail not updated since a week?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Graph API to report and create PKI about my Office Tenant.
Since a week, when I ask for [getOffice365ActiveUserDetail] the report date is still the same : 2019-01-06... So no data updated since the 6th january.

The other log are updated !

Answer (score 0):

You need a Premium license to view these activities and cannot see this information with a Free or Basic license. If you have recently switched to a Premium license it can take a few days for the data to show up and you'll only be able to retrieve data up to one week back. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reports-faq

If you already have the right licensing then it is likely a problem with the filter you are using.